# Write text in new Notepad

Tags: vba, excel

Could any one help me to write cell value to new instance of Notepad?

Here is the code I tried:

```
Sub a()
    Dim nt As String
    nt = Shell("notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)
    Print #1, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just write the text to a file and then open the file in its default application?

Comment: Here text will be changed every time. So would like to display the text in new notepad.

Comment: Hmm. So, do you want Notepad to show the contents of a cell in Excel? And you want Notepad to always show only the latest value in the cell?

Comment: I have prepared a calendar to display the data. If week <= 1 Then
    MsgBox Sheet11.Cells(4, "a"). But, MsgBox displays limited data. I think Notepad can help me to display the huge data.

Comment: Hmm. Without knowing more about your design, my thought would be to display the data directly in an excel spreadsheet, but a sheet that is formatted properly for your data.

Comment: I still don't get why you don't write to a text file and open that in Notepad. It's a lot simpler and does exactly what you seem to want.

Answer (score 5):

I had answered a similar question many years ago in vbforums.com but couldn't find it so I quickly re-wrote it for you. I have commented the code so you shall not have a problem understanding it.

Like you and me, we both have names, similarly windows have “handles” (hWnd), Class etc. Once you know what that hWnd is, it is easier to interact with that window. Findwindow API finds the hWnd of a particular window by using the class name. Read up on the rest of the APIs [Here](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php)

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim Ret As Long, ChildRet As Long
    Dim sString As String

    '~~> This is the value from the cell which
    '~~> you want to send to notepad
    sString = Range("A1").Value

    '~~> Start Notepad
    Ret = Shell("notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)

    '~~> Wait for it to load
    DoEvents

    '~~> Find notepad
    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Untitled - Notepad")

    '~~> Check if found
    If Ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find Notepad Window"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Find the "Edit Window" which is a child window of Notepad window
    ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)

    '~~> Send the message
    SendMessage ChildRet, WM_SETTEXT, 0, ByVal sString
End Sub
```

To get the classnames of windows, I usually use Spy ++ or uuSpy. See this is how I got the classname "Edit" of notepad using Spy ++

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much Siddharth.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: one more question, I have arranged Excel cell as one : Suman(Alt+enter) Two : Surya. Message box displays the data how I arranged in Cell. But Note pad continued the text as one : sumanTwo:Surya. can't we see the data how I arranged the data in Excel?

Comment: No for that you will have to copy and paste the data using `WM_PASTE` instead of `WM_SETTEXT` I would recommend googling on how to paste data using sendmessage. I may not be able to reply anymore today as I have a flight to catch in the next 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you. I used 
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Shell "notepad.exe", 3
SendKeys "^v"
VBA.AppActivate .Caption
.CutCopyMode = False
but data appears as I mentioned above :(
Please help to me once you are back